# Does modern Hinduism really accept the whole concept of Yugas as real or is it supposed to be allegorical?

Tags: scripture, kali-yuga, yuga, science, cosmology

I have seen the Yuga concept being peddled in a lot of scriptures - be it puranas or epics. Many shastras also seem to say it and even moral axioms are based on it it seems. Many things which were allowed in 'Satya Yuga' or 'Treta Yuga' are banned in 'Kali Yuga' which is supposed to have started around 3000 BC iirc. Many rituals like Aswamedha is not supposed to be conducted in Kali Yuga.

I hope that Hinduism doesn't accept the theory of 4 Yugas, because I have some bad news: it is not true. There were no 4 Yugas. The theory's timeline doesn't match with the history of the World, like, AT ALL. Each Yuga extends for lakhs of years and...we modern humans have been only around for 1.3 lakh years merely, out of which earliest civilization is only dated to around 10,000 BC and many cave paintings around 30,000 BC.

Before you cite the 'Cyclical theory of Universe', no, it is very different from what Hinduism says. The Cyclical theory of Universe suggests cycles previous to singularity which, let me remind you, happened literally 13.8 BILLION years ago. In between, there were literally no humans, and the Yuga theory mentions no void gap between successive cycles. As we say in Science, if our natural history is 24 hours, then humans appeared only a few minutes to 12'o clock at night. The History of this Universe is not human-centered unfortunately, unlike both Dharmic and Abrahamic cosmologies which place humans as the center of the Universe and the entire history to revolve around humans.

So, I hope that just like most things in Hinduism, this whole concept of Yuga should also have some allegorical interpretation, right? Right?

Comment: yuga theory is true. science will eventually catch up to the truth in scriptures. just as AIT was debunked, so will PIE, evolution (physical not spiritual) etc. Yuga theory definitely mentions a long period of pralaya. in fact there is a sub-pralaya where only 3 worlds are destroyed while brahma sleeps for 1 kalpa, while 4 higher worlds exist. just keep in mind one thing - YOU did not verify any of these "scientific" things - all you're doing is trusting other scientists who say they have peer-reviewed other scientists. similarly, we trust rishis who say they have peer-reviewed other rishis.

Comment: @mar truly, delulu has no solulu. And all this time, I thought you guys were different from Muslims

Comment: @Suradoe Uchicha, Some Hindus believe in yugas while others don't for reasons mentioned by you.

Comment: @SuradoeUchiha - muslims breathe air. hindus also breathe air. and all this time you thought hindus were different from muslims ?? lol

Comment: @mar Muslims kill apostates. Hindus afaik don't. Muslims believe, like Abrahamics, that this world was created 6-8000 years ago. I thought Hindus, being educated, don't and that Hindus subscribe to what has been found empirically and rationally. My bad that I thought religious people can be rational

Comment: @SuradoeUchiha - there are both similarities and differences between any 2 religions. believing that God created the universe is a similarity, not a difference. Believing that there is only 1 path to God vs. believing there are multiple, is a difference, not a similarity. Hindus believe the universe is eternally temporary - it is a cycle of creation and destruction going on forever. with each creation divided into yugas which themselves are cyclical.